# htaccess Clean URL - Two Behaviors

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to get two types of URL behaviors to work, but I get wired results, something like one making the other invalid.

How do I make both of the following to work at the same time. Here is my setting:

This one is so that all the PHP files in current+sub-folders could be used as clean URL.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

This one is so that Index file in route folder could read 'page' query parameter as URL

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are these in the same .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule 1 only adds .php to a filename that exits, that is if `{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/somepath/fred` exists the this is remapped to `{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/somepath/fred.php`.  Shouldn't the condition be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```